# Does a P2P, Open source, no port forwarding, low latency, messaging layer exist?

Tags: messaging, p2p, layer, portforwarding, low-latency

I have been looking for a low latency, p2p messaging layer (not necessarily a MQ) that should fulfill the following requirements but with no success. I have actually been using Resilio (Bittorrent Sync) and it just simply works without any configuration even when behind firewalls or on a NAT device etc. But it doesn’t meet my latency requirements (especially when multiple devices are storing ("sending") messages simultaneously in a shared folder.

Requirements:

- Must be free to utilize for commercial use (preferably open source).
- Must be available on Linux/Ubuntu.
- Must work out of the box i.e. no port forwarding etc. should be required even when behind firewalls or on a NAT device.
- Must be p2p (i.e. no centralized server).
- Must be somewhat scalable. Must support sub second delivery times of small (one kilobyte) messages when 10 devices are sending messages (one-to-many) simultaneously. So a total of 90 messages of one kilobyte delivered sub second. Each device distributes one message and receives 9 messages.
- Must have some kind of API.

I'm not sure how exactly Resilio are connecting to devices. But maybe the messaging layer I am looking for is utilizing some kind of signaling/STUN server for device discovery/connections. This should be fine as long as there are multiple public signaling/STUN servers that you can rely on (trying to avoid centralization). Technologies like WebRTC seem pretty promising but I just haven't found anything that works out of the box. However websites like https://otr.to and applications like Resilio tells me that a messaging layer/application with the above requirements should be possible?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should remove the "multicast" requirement from the title. Multicast or broadcast is a "send to all"-type address, normally it is not relevant when we are talking about p2p over the internet.

Comment: Done. I forgot to remove it from the title when I removed it from the requirements. What I am looking for is a solution with sub second communication from one-to-ten devices (approximately) but simultaneously. So a total of 90 messages of one kilobyte delivered sub second. So each device distributes one message and receives 9 messages. Not sure what the correct term for this kind of message distribution is.

Answer (score 0):

The sad state of reality is that IP multicast doesn't work over the open internet. Thus no file distribution p2p network uses it, which means you won't find one.

Comment: Also when multicast should only be between 10 devices?

Comment: the number of devices doesn't matter. what matters is whether the routers between them support it.

Comment: Ok. But what I mean is one-to-many communication which is fast (sub second transfers as described above), should that not be possible?

Comment: multicast overlays are possible, but not trivial since it's inherently less efficient than true multicast. look for p2p live streaming projects. basically, you're asking for too many properties at once. especially having to run it on a newish and fairly restricted technology stack (assuming webrtc implies browsers)

Comment: I am not implying the use of browsers :-) actually I would much rather use a messaging application with an API. Otr.to was just an example that shows a technology (webrtc I belive) which seems to be able to deliver messages sub second in a chat where 10 devices could be connected.